# GPUtil.showUtilization suddenly not working

Tags: python, gpu

Previously, when i run:

```
import GPUtil
GPUtil.showUtilization()
```

I could get correct GPU utilization result. However, today after I run some codes... Suddenly my GPU is not shown. It suddenly became

```
 ID  GPU  MEM
--------------
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

I tried restarting the server... it does not help..